# Deja rutas específicas sin efecto en ruby on rails y diseña

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, router, devise

Buenas noches como podría dejar sin efecto o eliminar estas 2 rutas, también deseo saber como podría hacer una redirección a otro sitio si no estoy iniciado sesión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para que podamos responder a tu pregunta con propiedad, ¿podrías por favor hacer lo siguiente? 1. Enseñarnos tu archivo de rutas (puesto que hablas de rutas y querremos ver qué tienes exactamente). 2. Mostrarnos listados de código como texto, en lugar de capturas de pantalla (hacen más sencillo leerlas y trabajar con ellas). Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: si no me equivoco, devise es la gema para el inicio de sesión, no? tendrías que consultar la documentación de la gema, para ver si lo que quieres es posible, en primer lugar. Esto también aplica para la segunda pregunta que tienes aquí.

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki